# Applying iterative function to every group in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, functional-programming

I have large pandas DataFrame with following format:

```
        prod_id     timestamp     text
150523  0006641040  9.393408e+08  text_1 
150500  0006641040  9.408096e+08  text_2 
150499  0006641041  1.009325e+09  text_3 
150508  0006641041  1.018397e+09  text_4 
150524  0006641042  1.025482e+09  text_5
```

DataFrame is sorted by `prod_id` and `timestamp`. What I am trying to do, is to enumerate a counter for every `prod_id` based on the `timestamp` from earliest to latest. For example, I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
        prod_id     timestamp     text    enum  
150523  0006641040  9.393408e+08  text_1  1
150500  0006641040  9.408096e+08  text_2  2 
150499  0006641041  1.009325e+09  text_3  1 
150508  0006641041  1.018397e+09  text_4  2 
150524  0006641042  1.025482e+09  text_5  1
```

I can do this iteratively quite easily by going through each row and increasing counter, but is there a way to do this in a more functional programming fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [324]: df
Out[324]:
        prod_id     timestamp    text
150523  6641040  9.393408e+08  text_1
150500  6641040  9.408096e+08  text_2
150501  6641040  9.408096e+08  text_3
150499  6641041  1.009325e+09  text_3
150508  6641041  1.018397e+09  text_4
150524  6641042  1.025482e+09  text_5

In [325]: df['enum'] = df.groupby(['prod_id'])['timestamp'].cumcount() + 1

In [326]: df
Out[326]:
        prod_id     timestamp    text  enum
150523  6641040  9.393408e+08  text_1     1
150500  6641040  9.408096e+08  text_2     2
150501  6641040  9.408096e+08  text_3     3
150499  6641041  1.009325e+09  text_3     1
150508  6641041  1.018397e+09  text_4     2
150524  6641042  1.025482e+09  text_5     1
```

**OLD answer:**

```
In [314]: df['enum'] = df.groupby(['prod_id'])['timestamp'].rank().astype(int)

In [315]: df
Out[315]:
        prod_id     timestamp    text  enum
150523  6641040  9.393408e+08  text_1     1
150500  6641040  9.408096e+08  text_2     2
150499  6641041  1.009325e+09  text_3     1
150508  6641041  1.018397e+09  text_4     2
150524  6641042  1.025482e+09  text_5     1
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! Didn't know rank() exists. Just a quick follow up though - I tried in on a subset of real data and it has some duplicates, namely when I timestamps are the same. Is there an easy way to just keep enumerating in this case to avoid same numbers?

Comment: @Bruhnswik, you are welcome! Please check updated answer - it should take care of duplicated values...